# socket in .jar won't connect to serverSocket

Tags: java, sockets, jar, serversocket

I wrote a simple instant messenger program and it worked perfectly fine in eclipse. I wanted to export it to a .jar and run it on multiple computers while my main computer hosted the java socketServer. The program works when running the server in a .jar but executing the client from eclipse. But when I run my client.jar it won't connect to the server. Both parts of my code are very long. I'm operating using the socket(ipaddress, port#) using my actual IPv4 address. I'm also operating on the port number 9000 I'm not sure if that has any affect or not. I've been searching this site and many other's but I can't seem to find an already open topic on this subject. I might add that I'm manually inputting my IPv4 address into the GUI because I've been switching between my desktop and laptop. My laptop IPv4 always changes so that's why I input it in manually

Code in Server.java

```
serverUser = new ServerSocket(9000);
textArea.append("User Server created on " + new Date() + "\n");
serverChat = new ServerSocket(9100);
textArea.append("Chat Server created on " + new Date() + "\n");

while(true)
{
    Socket socket = serverUser.accept();
    clientNum++;
    new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()).writeUTF("You have connected to the server");
    User user = new User(socket, new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream()).readUTF());
    userList.add(user);
```

Socket in client.java

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    boolean next = false;
    userName = userNameField.getText();
    password = new String(passwordField.getPassword());
    ipAddress = ipAddressField.getText();
    if(ipAddress.equals(""))
        status.setText("You must enter the IP Address of the Server");
    else
    {
        userNameField.setText("");
        ipAddressField.setText("");
        passwordField.setText("");
        query = "select * from User where userName = '" + userName + "' and password = '" + password + "'";
        try
        {
            line 328 ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
            if(rs.next())
            next = true;    
            rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from User");
        }
        catch(SQLException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        if(next)
        {
            tabbedPane.setEnabledAt(0, false);
            tabbedPane.setEnabledAt(1, true);
            tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(1);
            logout.setEnabled(true);
            try
            {
                socket = new Socket(ipAddress, 9000);
                output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                socket.setKeepAlive(true);
                socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
                output.writeUTF(userName);
                output.flush();
                status.setText(input.readUTF());
                setTitle(userName);
                Thread thread = new Thread(new UpdateTask(userList));
                thread.start();
            }
            catch(IOException ex)
            {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        else
            status.setText("Invalid user name or password");
        }
    }
```

Ok I got the error and I had the problem wrong of course. The problem ends up being the all annoying as always nullPointer which I have no clue how I'm getting either. 
Here's the error

```
C:\Users\Satokaheni\Programs\Java Workspace\Runnable Jars>java -jar Client.jar
Works
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at UserMenu$6.actionPerformed(UserMenu.java:328)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Man I feel real stupid I'm sorry for getting the problem wrong but can you help with this one?
I know the query is not null because I printed it out. So I don't know why it's giving me a nullPointer

I found why I think I'm getting the null Pointer

```
path to 'db/loginDB.db': 'C:\Users\Satokaheni\Programs\Java Workspace\Runnable Jars\db' does not exist
```

Here's my DB code

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
try
{
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:db/loginDB.db");
    statement = connection.createStatement();
}
catch(SQLException ex)
{
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

Thank You.

PS if you want I can post the code.

Comment: please share the code, at least the part dealing with the sockets.

Comment: And any error it might be producing

Comment: Can you check if you can connect to the server using telnet? the command would be "telnet <ipaddr> <port>" without the quotes.
Also, are you getting any error?

Comment: is your db query working fine? I see an empty catch block.

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException
    at UserMenu$6.actionPerformed(UserMenu.java:328)`. Please, mark the row number 328 in your `actionperformed()` code.

Comment: I think my problem stems from the .jar not being able to find the path to my .db file. I've already added the sqlitejdbc-v056.jar to the java build path in my eclipse project. So I have no clue how to put that code in to where it finds my db

Comment: May be you can't find database file. But if so, you must see error message (you print it in the catch clause) in console. Are you seeing it? Is it a valid path to your db file `C:\Users\Satokaheni\Programs\Java Workspace\Runnable Jars\db`?

Comment: I see that but I don't know why the jar should have to reach outside itself to find the database. Can't it just find the .db in the jar itself? If not I'll just add the database folder. I added the db folder and it works but there should be some way to put the db folder in the .jar.

Comment: Discussion of similar problem. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358756/how-to-pack-a-sqlite-database-into-a-jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358756/how-to-pack-a-sqlite-database-into-a-jar)

Comment: can you check if your statement object is null? I really can't make anything out which line the error is on.(thanks to the partial code)

Comment: The issue was it didn't have a path to the database so it couldn't connect. I added the DB folder to the folder containing my client.jar and it works. Nestor answered my question on if I could put them all in one but it seems I'll just keep them separate

Comment: Thank You guys for all the help with my program ^_^